# Match capture group fixed number of times

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of 5-letter strings. For each string, I would like to match only if the string contains 3 instances of the same letter, i.e.:

```
Case 1: 'aabbc'  ->  no match
Case 2: 'bbbcc'  ->  match 'bbb'
Case 3: 'ddcdc'  ->  match 'ddd'
```

My best regex attempt is:

```
(.){1}(?!\1)*\1{1}(?!\1)*\1{1}
```

This works for case 1 (where there is no match) and case 2 (where the 3 instances are adjacent), but not for case 3 (where the 3 instances are separated by at least one other letter).

Is there a regex that will work for case 3? Ideally I would like to also extract the locations of the 3 matching instances from the string.

Comment: You are discovering the limits of what regexes are useful for.  While someone may come up with a very advanced regex that can do this, it's best to use program logic to solve this.  Unless you treat this as a puzzle.  That being said, some tasks are just impossible to accomplish with a regex.

Comment: @Joel, this can be done with a fair simple regex.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, great.... your move, sir!

Comment: What about `aaaaa` or `abbbb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below pattern catches what you need and should capture the edge cases. The first capturing group can be modified to just be the subset of characters you need to search for if there is a limited list of expected values. Putting the `\1`s in capturing groups means that you should be able to extract the index of the capturing groups from the match via `.start()` (getting the starting index of the capturing group), meeting your bonus goal.

```py
>>> pattern = r"(.).*(\1).*(\1)"
>>> x = re.search(pattern, "ababb")
>>> x.groups()
('b', 'b', 'b')
>>> x.start(1)
1
>>> x.start(2)
3
>>> x.start(3)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern `([a-z]).*?\1.*?\1` does what you want, although there are likely to be edge cases that would complicate it.

The pattern looks for a lowercase letter three times, with 0 or more characters between them.

You could then extract just the capturing groups to get your match locations.

At the moment, the pattern only looks for any lowercase letter repeated three times, but you could change the initial capturing group - `([a-z])` - if you wanted to capture something else.

[Demo](https://regexr.com/524so)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to determine if one character appears at least three times.

```
^.*(.).*\1.*\1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iqqLhm/1/)

This does not check that the characters are letters but it does work with any characters. To restrict to letters change each `.` to `[a-z]` or `[a-zA-Z]`, as appropriate.

To see if one character appears *exactly* 3 times, change the regex to:

```
^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){3,}).*(.).*\2.*\2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iqqLhm/2/)

```
^           # match beginning of line
(?!         # begin negative lookahead
  .*        # match 0+ chars
  (.)       # match a char in cap grp 2
  (?:.*\1)  # match 0+ chars followed by content of cap grp 1
            # in a non-cap grp
  {3,}      # execute non-cap grp 3+ times 
)           # end negative lookahead
.*          # match 0+ chars
(.)         # match char in cap grp 2
.*          # match 0+ chars
\2          # match content of cap grp 2
.*          # match 0+ chars
\2          # match content of cap grp 2
```